# Laravel: sequential queue with beanstalkd

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, beanstalkd

#### The project:

Users / Customers can upload a PDF - for reasons. This can happen simultanously.

---

#### The goal:

A large PDF (with many pages) must be converted. While converting the pages every individual step (4 different steps for every page) must get logged, so i can show the **progress of the current step** and calculate the processed percentage.

---

#### The  situation:

After I get the amount of pages in the uploaded pdf, I run a `for` loop and push the `convert job` into the `beanstalkd queue`. Everything works fine.

---

#### The problem:

The pages getting processed in a different order than they came in through the loop. This behaviour results in confusing log entries and can not be used to display the progress.

`beanstalkd config`

```
[program:worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
directory=/home/vagrant/Code/project
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
```

I've set `numprocs` to 8 so that multiple users can upload their files simultanously, but it results un unwanted chaotic order.

If I change `numprocs` to 1 it runs in correct order but than I can not run multiple converting processes at once.

What should I do?

---

***EDIT***

I'm so dumb. Just solved the problem. But for the glory of satan (and so someone can earn the points) I'll post the solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody answered; here is the solution:

instead of running a `for loop` and pushing all the page converting jobs into the queue, I just push a single job into the queue which converts one page and creates a new job for the next page (if there is one) after it's done.